# Read only 6 columns from a S3 file with more columns (number of columns will change dynamically) into a table

Tags: amazon-s3, copy, amazon-redshift

The issue is that the number of columns in the S3 file can dynamically change over time.

I tried the following:

```
DROP  TABLE test.table;
--
CREATE  TABLE test.table
( 
    c1 character varying(65535) NOT NULL ENCODE lzo, 
    c2 character varying(65535) NOT NULL ENCODE lzo, 
    c3 character varying(65535) NOT NULL ENCODE lzo, 
    c4 character varying(65535) NOT NULL ENCODE lzo, 
    c5 character varying(65535) NOT NULL ENCODE lzo, 
    c6 character varying(65535) NOT NULL ENCODE lzo 
) DISTSTYLE AUTO;

COPY test.table (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6) 
FROM s3 location
IAM ROLE xyz;
```

My s3 file for now has the following columns

```
(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7)
```

Tomorrow it can become

```
(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8)
```

and I only want to get

```
(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6)
```

The issue is that when I run the above code, I get the error "Extra columns found"

Comment: In which format your file in s3? As I remember .json automatically skips not needed columns

Comment: .csv format is what my file is in